# Sorting Pandas data frame with groupby and conditions

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to sort a data frame based on groups meeting conditions.

The I'm getting a syntax error for the way I'm sorting the groups. 
And I'm losing the initial order of the data frame before attempting the above.

This is the order of sorting that I'm trying to achieve:

1) Sort on First and Test columns.

2) Test==1 groups, sort on Secondary then by Final column.

---Test==0 groups, sort on Final column only.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"First":[100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200],"Test":[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],"Secondary":[.1,.1,.1,.2,.2,.3,.3,.3,.3,.4,.4],"Final":[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.10,11.11]})

def sorter(x):
    if x["Test"]==1:
        x.sort_values(['Secondary','Final'], inplace=True)
    else:
        x=x.sort_values('Final', inplace=True)


df=df.sort_values(["First","Test"],ascending=[False, False]).reset_index(drop=True)


df.groupby(['First','Test']).apply(lambda x: sorter(x))

df
```

---

```
Expected result:

First Test Secondary Final
200     1   0.4     10.1
200     1   0.3*    9.9*
200     1   0.3*    8.8*

200     0   0.4     11.11*
200     0   0.3     7.7*

100     1   0.5     2.2
100     1   0.1*    3.3*
100     1   0.1*    1.1*

100     0   0.3     6.6*
100     0   0.2     5.5*
100     0   0.2     4.4*
```

Comment: do you have any other values in test other than one? if not i think the answer below should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try of sorting in descending order without groupby, 
w.r.t sequence you gave, the order of sorting will change.will it work for you

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"First":[100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200],"Test":[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],"Secondary":[.1,.5,.1,.9,.4,.1,.3,.3,.3,.4,.4],"Final":[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.10,11.11]})

df = df.groupby(['First','Test']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['First','Test','Secondary','Final'],ascending=False) if x.iloc[0]['Test']==1 else x.sort_values(['First','Test','Final'],ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
df.sort_values(['First','Test'],ascending=[True,False])
```

Out:

```
    Final   First   Secondary   Test
3   2.20    100 0.5 1
4   3.30    100 0.1 1
5   1.10    100 0.1 1
0   6.60    100 0.1 0
1   5.50    100 0.4 0
2   4.40    100 0.9 0
8   10.10   200 0.4 1
9   9.90    200 0.3 1
10  8.80    200 0.3 1
6   11.11   200 0.4 0
7   7.70    200 0.3 0
```

Comment: The reason I was attempting it differently in my code is because the Secondary column should come into play where Test==1 and should be ignored where Test==0. The solution doesn't work on a slightly modified data frame df=pd.DataFrame({"First":[100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200],"Test":[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],"Secondary":[.1,.5,.1,.9,.4,.1,.3,.3,.3,.4,.4],"Final":[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.10,11.11]})  Any idea how to modify the code to avoid the syntax error? Thank you

Comment: HI @Kdog , i just incorporated the change :-)

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to sort subsets separately and replace the values in the original df.
This came up in other solutions to pandas sorting problems.

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.DataFrame({"First":[100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200],"Test":[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],"Secondary":[.1,.5,.1,.9,.4,.1,.3,.3,.3,.4,.4],"Final":[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.10,11.11]})

df.sort_values(['First','Test','Secondary','Final'],ascending=False, inplace=True)

index_subset=df[df["Test"]==0].index
sorted_subset=df[df["Test"]==0].sort_values(['First','Final'],ascending=False)

df.loc[index_subset,:]=sorted_subset.values

print(df)
```